# NFC HCE on Google Nexus 7 (2012) not working with ACR122 reader

Tags: java, android, nfc, nexus-7, hce

I write and app for connecting with android system by NFC, tested on Google Nexus 4 and 5, and all works fine but with Google Nexus 7 (2012) not work. Can you help me.
Code from application on Java:

```
if (cardTerminal.isCardPresent()) {
            try {
                Card card = cardTerminal.connect("direct");
                ApduTagReaderWriter readerWriter = new ApduTagReaderWriter(new AcsDirectChannelTag(TagType.ISO_DEP,
                        null, card));
                try {
                    IsoDepTamaCommunicator tamaCommunicator = new IsoDepTamaCommunicator(readerWriter, readerWriter);
                    String data = tamaCommunicator.connectAsInitiator(); 
                    }
                }
}
```

Here is IsoDepTamaCommunicator and inListPassiveTargetResp.getNumberOfTargets() returns 0 with Nexus 7, but not with nexus 4,5.

```
public class IsoDepTamaCommunicator extends AbstractTamaCommunicator {

private static final String EMPTY_STRING = "";
private boolean IsConnected = false;
private static final byte[] CLA_INS_P1_P2 = { 0x00, (byte)0xA4, 0x04, 0x00 };
private static final byte[] AID_ANDROID = { (byte)0xF0, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06 };

public IsoDepTamaCommunicator(ByteArrayReader reader, ByteArrayWriter writer) {
    super(reader, writer);
}

public String connectAsInitiator() throws IOException {
        InListPassiveTargetResp inListPassiveTargetResp = sendMessage(new InListPassiveTargetReq((byte) 1, (byte) 0,
                new byte[0]));

        if (inListPassiveTargetResp.getNumberOfTargets() > 0) {
            System.out.println("TargetData: " + NfcUtils.convertBinToASCII(inListPassiveTargetResp.getTargetData()));
            if (inListPassiveTargetResp.isIsoDepSupported()) {
                System.out.println("IsoDep Supported");

                byte[] selectAidApdu = createSelectAidApdu(AID_ANDROID);
                DataExchangeResp resp = sendMessage(new DataExchangeReq(inListPassiveTargetResp.getTargetId(),
                        false, selectAidApdu, 0, selectAidApdu.length));

                String dataIn = new String(resp.getDataOut());
                if (dataIn.startsWith("test:")) {
                    dataIn = dataIn.substring(5, dataIn.length());
                    IsConnected = true;
                    return dataIn;
                }

            } else {
                System.out.println("IsoDep NOT Supported");
                return EMPTY_STRING;
            }
        }

    return EMPTY_STRING;
}

private byte[] createSelectAidApdu(byte[] aid) {
    byte[] result = new byte[6 + aid.length];
    System.arraycopy(CLA_INS_P1_P2, 0, result, 0, CLA_INS_P1_P2.length);
    result[4] = (byte)aid.length;
    System.arraycopy(aid, 0, result, 5, aid.length);
    result[result.length - 1] = 0;
    return result;
}
}
```

On android device sends message function is:

```
public class MyHostApduService extends HostApduService {

@Override
public byte[] processCommandApdu(byte[] apdu, Bundle extras) {

    String message = "test:message";

    return message.getBytes();
}

@Override
public void onDeactivated(int reason) {
}
}
```

and in androidManifest.xml added the next service:

```
<service
        android:name=".MyHostApduService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NFC_SERVICE" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.action.HOST_APDU_SERVICE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.host_apdu_service"
            android:resource="@xml/apduservice" />
    </service>
```

All works fine with Google Nexus 4 and 5 and not work with Google Nexus 7.
On all testing devices installed Android version 5.0

Comment: Have you  been able to make it work? I am facing similar issue while testing Google Nexus devices (one having Kitkat and other Lollipop). It worked fine Google Nexus 4 and 5 (both Kitkat).

Comment: No. I still in search =(